# Creating a filter to color the incoming email — not the “star label”

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Does Gmail have the ability to create a filter, based on sender, to "color" the incoming email?  For example, in my email window, I want to see all emails coming from my boss in red (not the label’s color, the actual from and subject), team members in blue etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t do that in Gmail.